# js задачка начинающего

Tags: javascript

есть строка '123456', нужно сделать из нее '214365'

```js
let str = '123456'
str = str.split('')
for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i += 2) {
    str.splice(i, 0, str.splice(i+1, 1))
}
console.log(str)
```

почему этот код дает ответ не ["2", "1", "4", "3", "6", "5"] а [Array(1), "1", Array(1), "3", Array(1), "5"] то есть те значения которые нужны, но внутри собственных массивов?

p.s понятно что используя str.join('') я получу нужный ответ, тут суть вопроса почему? а не как?

Comment: Дайте вопросу заголовок, отражающий суть проблемы.

Comment: `console.log( '123456'.replace(/(.)(.)/g, "$2$1") );` — можно еще так. Наконец в какой-то задаче пригодилась сиськорегулярка)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вы превращаете строку в массив и применяете метод массива [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), который возвращает уже не строку, а массив удалённых элементов.

Answer (score 3):

так попробуйте

```js
let str = '123456'
str = str.split('')

for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i += 2) {
    str.splice(i, 0, str.splice(i+1, 1)[0])
}
console.log(str)
```

А всё потому что str.splice(i+1, 1) возвращает [массив](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
array.splice(start, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]])
```

> Массив, содержащий удалённые элементы. Если будет удалён только один
> элемент, вернётся массив из одного элемента. Если никакие элементы не
> будут удалены, вернётся пустой массив.

Если воспользоваться идеей @wololo, чтоб не путаться в JS существует [a, b] = [b, a]; [деструктивное присваивание](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring-assignment)

```js
let str = '123456'
str = str.split('')

for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i += 2) {
  [str[i], str[i+1]] = [str[i+1], str[i]];
}

console.log(str);
```

Comment: На каждый второй элемент массива происходит два вызова `splice`. Это точно хорошая идея с точки зрения производительности? Может лучше как-нибудь так: `for(let i = 1; i < str.length; i += 2) [str[i], str[i-1]] = [str[i-1], str[i]];`?

Comment: Я лишь поправил код автора чтоб получилось что ему нужно. Я бы решил и вовсе по другому

Comment: Ок, я спрашивал сугубо из любопытства, не с целью критики ответа :)

Comment: по идее нужно пройтись и поменять четные с нечетными местами. и Да ваш вариант вполне приемлем

Answer (score 0):

```
 function reverse(str){
let arr = str.split('');
let newArr = [];
for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i +=2){
    newArr.push(arr[i] + arr[i - 1]);
}
return newArr.join('');
}

 console.log(reverse('123456'));
```